# Client only graphql query with Apollo Client

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client

Say I have a query `getUser($id)` but I'm finding I mostly call it for the currently authenticated user.  Using Apollo client, how would I define a client side only query, say `getMyUser()` who's implementation would do the following:

1. check currently logged in user, get their id (could be from wherever, in my case it would be the indexedDB)
2. call the getUser($id) query
3. respond with result of `getUser($id)`

Note: This is just one use case, ultimately, I need a way to define a whole set of queries and mutations that wrap more low level queries and mutations in order to avoid having to implement all new endpoints on the server.

Comment: Never pass the current user id in from the client - get it from the context on the server. Otherwise a client can impersonate a different user.

Comment: I mean, to be fair, you shouldn't be relying on the client id to verify auth status.  So long as you handle that on a different layer, passing the client id from the client is not an issue.  But regardless, what I'm really trying to get at is, is there a simple way to compose queries and mutations on the client?

Comment: You can use a `cache-only` cache policy to run a query exclusively on the client.assuming the results have been previously obtained via a network request  A mutation makes less sense.